# How to use UserControl events to MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I am creating a WPF application using MVVM pattern.

In my application I have a mainwindow which works like main template of the app. I created a `TreeView` in a `UserControl` that works like a menu.

In the main window all the presentation is hosted in tab controls, so every item from my `TreeView` is actually a new tab.

The tab control is defined on the main window.

So my question is how can Iopen a new tab  (press an item from `TreeView`) in my current tab control when the event handlers of the `TreeView` are on the `UserControls` code behind file and not in the main window file and so I cannot interact with it?

Is it possible somehow to host the event handlers of the `TreeView` in the code-behind file of the main window?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this

**Usercontrol.xaml**

```
<TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeViewHandler" />
```

**Usercontrol.cs**

```
public delegate void TreeViewSelectedItemHandler(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e);
public event TreeViewSelectedItemHandler TreeViewSelectedItemChanged;

private void TreeViewHandler(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    //Capture event from usercontrol and execute defined event
    if (TreeViewSelectedItemChanged != null)
    {
        TreeViewSelectedItemChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

**Window.xaml**

```
<local:myUsercontrol TreeViewSelectedItemChanged="myHandler" />
```

**Window.cs**

```
private void myHandler(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: @pilixonis Go ahead and accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks.